# SQL subquery matches hard-coded IN criteria, but not subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, subquery, in-subquery

I have a group of people who have taken a test.  I can select their IDs with this query:

```
SELECT person_id
FROM tests
WHERE test_code = 1234
```

I'd like to pull these individuals' records from a demographics table, so I tried this subquery to do so:

```
SELECT *
FROM demographics d
WHERE d.person_id IN (
    SELECT t.person_id
    FROM tests t
    WHERE t.test_code = 1234
)
```

... but I'm not getting any results.  If I take a couple of the IDs from the (functional) subquery and hard-code them into the IN criteria:

```
SELECT *
FROM demographics d
WHERE d.person_id IN (01123, 58132)
```

... the query works.  I've got to be missing something really fundamental here - do you know what it is?

Possible complicating factors: t.person_id is char13, d.person_id is varchar50.  This is MS SQL Server 9.0.4035; I'm working in SQL Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem may be that TESTS.PERSON_ID is coming in with trailing blanks on it since it's declared as CHAR instead of VARCHAR.  I'm not sure how to remove trailing blanks in SQL Server (it's been a while since I used it), but in Oracle I'd use the TRUNC function, as in

```
SELECT * 
  FROM demographics d 
  WHERE d.person_id IN ( 
    SELECT TRUNC(t.person_id )
      FROM tests t 
      WHERE t.test_code = 1234 )
```

Edit: I believe the equivalent function in SQL Server is RTRIM.

Comment: Oracle: TRUNC(t.person_id)
SQL: LTRIM(RTRIM(t.person_id))

Comment: @Vidar, @ig0774: I looked it up and you're both right; LTRIM(RTRIM(...)) is equivalent to Oracle's TRUNC, but RTRIM is really what's needed.  Thanks.  :-)

Comment: I believe that this the issue.  The SQL Server trim functions are LTRIM and RTRIM.  Try the hard-coded query using ('        01123', '        58132') as the argument to the IN clause to verify.

Comment: Actually, it was *leading zeroes*. The demographic IDs all have three zeroes affixed to the front... hmm. But this got me thinking about the right things. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

First off, you are not aliasing tests properly.  Should be:

```
SELECT *
FROM demographics d
WHERE d.person_id IN (
    SELECT t.person_id
    FROM **tests t**
    WHERE t.test_code = 1234
)
```

Secondly, if t.person_id returns any NULLs you will not get any results.

Comment: NULLs only have this affect for `NOT IN`

Comment: Sorry, that was just a typo.  Good attention to detail, though.

Comment: @Martin — Thank you, I stand corrected.  The database I most use does not implement that NULL issue according the SQL standard, something I usually appreciate.  Until recently, SQLite3 did the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM demographics d 
WHERE d.person_id IN ( 
    SELECT person_id 
    FROM tests 
     WHERE test_code = 1234 
)
```

Have you tried it without the t. in the subquery? as looking at your original subquery your not giving the table tests an alias of t...

Comment: Yes, I had validated that the subquery worked as written (which, ahem, was not exactly as I had it written here - Larry caught a typo in my table aliasing).

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried a subquery in an IN clause, so I can't guarantee this works, but try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM demographics d 
WHERE d.person_id IN ( 
    (SELECT t.person_id 
    FROM t.tests 
    WHERE t.test_code = 1234) 
)
```

I simply added parentheses around your subquery, which is common practice. Again, I've never tried a subq in an IN clause so can't guarantee this works but it's worth a shot.